# How to make one slice call reducer corresponding to another dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using React and I've got a Redux-Toolkit (RTK) state slice that is persisted with localStorage (I'm using the `redux-persist` library). Simplified it's like that:

```js
const initLocations = []

const locationsPersistentSlice = createSlice({
  {
  name: "locations",
  initLocations,
  reducers: {
    addLocation(prevState, action) {
      // adding new location to store
    },
    clearLocations() {
      return []
    }
  }
})
```

It works synchronously and perfectly fine.

But, I want to add second slice, `locationInfoSlice`, that should fetch data when `addLocation()` action is dispatched, using the very last location in the list.

How can I achieve that? I thought about `extraReducers` or `asyncThunk`, but didn't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, I want to add second slice `locationInfoSlice`, that should fetch
> data when `addLocation()` action is dispatched, using the very last
> location in the list.

If I'm understanding your post/question correctly you effectively want to dispatch *some* single action and do the following:

- Store a location in the `state.locations` array
- Handle some asynchronous action/logic to fetch some data using the last location in the `state.locations` array.

> How can I achieve that? I thought about `extraReducers` or `asyncThunk`,
> but didn't get it right.

You'll likely need to use both. `extraReducers` alone won't work since reducer functions are pure synchronous functions without side-effects, e.g. they can't fetch data asynchronously. My suggestion would be to create a Thunk that dispatches the `addLocation` action to update the `state.locations` state, and also makes the data fetch you need that can return a value that will be used to update the `locationInfoSlice`'s state in `extraReducers`.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { addLocation } from '../locationsPersistentSlice';

export const addLocationAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "locations/addLocationAsync",
  async (location, thunkApi) => {
    // dispatch to add new location
    thunkApi.dispatch(addLocation(location));

    try {
      // asynchronous fetch logic
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithError(error);
    }
  },
);
```

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = [];

const locationsPersistentSlice = createSlice({
  name: "locations",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addLocation(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    clearLocations() {
      return initialState;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addLocation,
  clearLocations,
} = locationsPersistentSlice.actions;

export default locationsPersistentSlice.reducer;
```

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { addLocationAsync } from './action';

const initialState = /* whatever this initial state value is */;

const locationInfoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "locationInfo",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(addLocationAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // update state with fetched data
      })
      .addCase(addLocationAsync.rejected, (state, action) => {
        // update state with error status???
      })
      .addCase(addLocationAsync.pending, (state, action) => {
        // set any pending/loading state
      });
  },
});

export default locationInfoSlice.reducer;
```

In the UI instead of dispatching the `addLocation` action directly it will now dispatch the `addLocationAsync` action.

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { addLocationAsync } from './action';

...

const dispatch = useDispatch();

...

dispatch(addLocationAsync(/* some location value */));

...
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. Now I can both use async and sync version in specific cases!!!